# ListBox bound to List is not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

This is the simplest example of a program that demonstrates the problem. I need to bind a List to ListBox. Yes, the data structure must be a list, not an ObservableCollection (but if it's needed, I can build a wrapper or something).
In this program there is a listbox and a button which removes the first item in the list. But when the item is removed, the ListBox contents are not updated even though oneway binding is configured. I need it to get updated on item removal.

```
class Data: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<string> items;
    public List<string> Items { get { return items; } }

    public Data(List<string> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void RemoveFirstItem()
    {
        items.Remove(items[0]);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="TheListBox" Margin="0,0,0.138,46.231" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="212,292,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Data data;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new Data(new List<string>{ "1", "2", "3", "4" });
        this.DataContext = data;

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        data.RemoveFirstItem();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, the data structure must be a list, not an ObservableCollection (but if it's needed, I can build a wrapper or something)

It's pretty simple, The `ListBox` UI(Xaml) updating is all based on a few interfaces such as [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and few more

These interfaces instruct the UI when an item they hold gets added / removed / refreshed ...

A `List` does not implement these interfaces(it implements things such as `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`...). So having your `ListBox.ItemsSource` bound to a collection of type `List` isn't going to get you the benefits of using an `ObservableCollection` with updates in the UI.

Sure, if you're forced to use a `List` and wouldn't mind how you're achieving the result, Every-time you remove an item from your `List`, reset the Window's `DataContext` (set the `DataContext` to `null` before the remove and again to `data` after the remove). However this is just insane if someone forced you to have to do that and you should prolly have a chat with them and explain why it's insane.

As for your wrapper idea, sure you can build your own custom collection that say implements `IEnumerable`, `INotifyCollectionChanged`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` and internally hold a `List` or whatever, but your `ListBox.ItemSource` should be of this type wrapper to get the updating behavior.

You haven't mentioned why exactly you are forced to not use an `ObservableCollection<T>`, however if you can you prolly should just use it than invent your own custom collection for simple stuff.